# How do you do TSQL CHARINDEX or TSQL IN in BQL?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to determine if the first two characters of a field value match one of a finite list of values ie ("RG", "HC", "LP", etc) maybe 5-10 of these values. I dont care which one it is, just that it is "valid".

In SQL i could do it with CHARINDEX, or IN - how can i do this with BQL?

I could probably do a SWITCH/CASE but it seems inefficient to spell them all out like that.

Specifically, I am trying to do this in a DBCalced attribute for a field:

```
[PXDBCalced(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<Substring<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr,int1, int2>, In<EDType>>, Substring<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr,int1, int2>>, StringEmpty>), typeof(string))]
```

The In above doesnt seem to do what i expected - not sure what it is intended for or how to use IN<> as i found no doc. I defined EDType as a constant string with all my values split by commas.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Have a boolean field that returns True/false if that's the case? Or run queries against this calculated field? Please provide more info on the context, it is not clear why you're doing it :)

Comment: I want to have this field be derived from another field in the record - if the first two chars match one of my standard values then use those chars otherwise leave field blank.

Comment: Have you thought of using the FieldUpdated event (in this case I think it's INItemLotSerial_LotSerialNbr_FieldUpdated) to simply set the other field using plain C# code?

Comment: I did consider that, but that would need to be tied to a specific Graph correct? I wanted this to happen regardless of which Graph might use it.

Comment: Well, you could also create a custom attribute hooked to the field which listens to the event as well...

Comment: I have never added a custom attribute like that- is there an example in one of the classes i could follow?

Comment: Just added an answer with a simplified sample

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it through pure BQL statements, my recommendation would be to handle the FieldUpdated event. You can do it from the graph, or you can create a custom attribute that you will apply to your field. There's a few different ways that you can create this custom attribute, but the simplest definition would look something like that:

```
private sealed class MyCustomBehaviourAttribute : PXEventSubscriberAttribute, IPXFieldUpdatedSubscriber
{
    public void FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add your logic here
    }
}
```

You may also search inside the source code (using the find in files function on screen SM.20.45.70) and search for attributes which implement IPXFieldUpdatedSubscriber, or that call FieldUpdated.AddHandler to subscribe to the event manually.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this now. I was able to get it working with the Switch/Case approach, but this would be better.

Comment: Can you post the switch/case solution you used ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt fit this into a comment but i used this attribute:

```
     [PXDBCalced(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<Substring<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr, int1, int2>, Equal<EDRG>,
                                Or<Substring<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr, int1, int2>, Equal<EDAP>,
                                Or<Substring<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr, int1, int2>, Equal<EDHC>,
                                Or<Substring<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr, int1, int2>, Equal<EDRN>,
                                Or<Substring<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr, int1, int2>, Equal<EDPP>,
                                Or<Substring<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr, int1, int2>, Equal<EDPT>
                                >>>>>
                                >, Substring<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr, int1, int2>>, StringEmpty>), typeof(string))]
```

Where the EDRG, etc are constants.

Like i said, not the prettiest, but seems effective.

Answer (score 0):

`In<T>` is not supposed to be used with anything but parameters (e.g. `Required<T>` or `Optional<T>`) because it is accepting a vector or values as its second operand, that can be achieved now only passing an array to match a parameter.